# .bashrc not sourced on Intellij IDEA's terminal

Tags: bash, intellij-idea

I have some aliased defined on my `.bashrc` that I'd like to use on my Intellij IDEA's terminal. Why is `.bashrc` not sourced?

Comment: Useful to understand why: [Why doesn't .bashrc run automatically?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/13019/116146) and [What is the difference between .bash_profile and .bashrc?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc)

Comment: My issue was with launching from the doc as a GUI for Android Studio. I updated my system-wide path from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3756686/1451443

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`.bashrc` is only loaded when Bash is running in "interactive" mode. For some reason, IntelliJ defaults to running Bash in non-interactive mode, but this is easy to change. Open the IntelliJ Settings window, then open "Tools -> Terminal", and add `-i` to the Shell path.

(Note that in this screenshot, I have also changed the default shell, because I'm on a Mac, which makes it difficult to update `/bin/bash`. Unless you have installed a different version of Bash, do not blindly copy this change!)

[image]

Comment: This is best solution and this must be marked as best answer!

Comment: So if your `Terminal > Shell path` setting calls `bash -i` (interactive), it will run `~/.bashrc` on opening a new tab; if it calls `bash` (non-interactive), it will run `~/.bash_profile`.  *Checked against WebStorm 2020.3.3 on macOS Catalina.*

Comment: This solution does not work on my windows git bash environment. Instead what did work was this solution provided: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205437150/comments/204862230

Comment: @Barney Interesting... `--login -i` should also work, but `login` may not be what you want. I don't know why `-i` on its own wouldn't fix the issue for you, though.

Comment: @KyleStrand oh `--login` or `-l` alone (without `-i`) does what I need which is to source `.bash_profile`. This SO question is about `.bashrc` so I now realize this is not apples to oranges. Thank you anyway and feel free to disregard!

Answer (score 17):

Had the same issue with IntelliJ.
Solved this by setting the value `/bin/bash --login` in `setting->Tools->Terminal->Shell path`.

`/bin/bash --login` forces the bash to read the `~/.bash_profile`.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205437150-Terminal-not-sourcing-bash-profile?page=1#community_comment_360000167679

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. However I do not have a ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 12):

In your home directory, add theses lines to `.profile` (create the file if it does not exist), in order to source `.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$SHELL" = "/bin/bash" ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: Kenavoz, I had found this solution.. I asked this question to find out why it's not source by default and why your solution works. thanks

Comment: Did you define you bash path in the Intellij IDEA's terminal settings ?

Comment: it's `/bin/bash` by default.. Why would I have to?

Comment: I don't know the default. Bash is not universal and it could haved explained why `.bashrc` is not sourced.

Comment: Makes sense! That's probably the case.

Comment: Kenavoz, I just checked and my `~/.profile` has something like: # if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
 . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi     I thought it should be enough. right?

Comment: I would change the file test to `if [ -r "$HOME/.bashrc" ]` to check if it exists and has read permissions. You may also test the `$BASH` variable instead of `$BASH_VERSION`.

Answer (score 10):

For me, changing the line

```
Exec="/opt/idea-IU-183.4284.148/bin/idea.sh" %f
```

to

```
Exec=bash -ic "/opt/idea-IU-183.4284.148/bin/idea.sh" %f
```

worked. We exploit the hack that the interactive shell loads `.bashrc` :)

Comment: While the solution is highly installation-specific, I've found it useful in another case. I use node.js with `nvm` and for node to be available in `PATH`, `.bashrc` should be executed before IDE. I've improved the solution like this: `bash -ic "exec /path/to/webstorm.sh %f"` That is, handle `%f` and use `exec` to replace bash.

Comment: This solution works for me with Ubuntu 20.04.  Thanks!

Comment: Also works for me on Kubuntu 20.04. NPM installed via NPM was not available during maven builds delegating to shell exec.

Comment: This worked atleast on ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. If some one failing to find path where to replace. Here it is
~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-rider.desktop or intellj or webstorm

Answer (score 9):

On Mac OSX Catalina, `"/bin/bash"` and `~/.zprofile` worked for me:

[image]

### Update:

Apple has changed the default shell to `zsh.` Therefore you have to rename your configuration files. `.bashrc` is now `.zshrc` and `.bash_profile` is now `.zprofile`.

Comment: The important information for me was, that ZSH is now the new standard in Mac OS Catalina.

Answer (score 3):

My settings are in ~/.bash_profile . I solved it using:

```
echo "source ~/.bash_profile" >> .profile
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo echo ". ~/.bashrc" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel As I understood, idea loads only default bash profile. With adding source of your home .bashrc at the end of it, it will be loaded by default. btw, first answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: Even though this might work, I wouldn't do this. I quite often make changes to my .bashrc -file. The .bashrc -file contains configuration for an individual user whereas /etc/bash.bashrc is used for every user using the system. The command suggested simply adds my entire configuration to the system configuration which will then apply it to every user using the system. Apparently Intellij IDEA picks up the system-file, but not the file intended for the individual user.

Answer (score 1):

Because `>` operator doesn't pass the sudo permissions to the write process.

I did this :

```
echo ". ~/.bashrc" | sudo tee /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that `.bashrc` isn't sourced only when I first install IntelliJ and run it directly via the `idea.sh` script in `bin/`.

Once I create the desktop entry via `Tools -> Create Desktop Entry...` and start it from the Ubuntu dash, `.bashrc` is sourced properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have recently moved to zsh from bash then go to `~/.zshrc` file and update $PATH variable there:

Default value in `.zshrc`:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Change to same PATH variable set in `.bashrc` and uncomment it

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:<my-bash-paths>:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me. What did work is

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

...then manually adding my `export` and `alias` commands here to make them system wide.

But be careful, do NOT mess up the PATH or you'll have trouble logging back in to your desktop environment, or many other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because the default shell had been changed to `zsh`.

I echoed the shell name with `echo $SHELL` to see this (thanks [How to get default shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375519/how-to-get-default-shell)).

Then I changed it back to `/bin/bash` with this command: `chsh -s /bin/bash` (thanks https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/100476/176809).

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash script with the content;

```
echo "source ~/.bash_profile" >> .profile
```

Then in Intellij go to preferences/tools/Startup Tasks;

create a run configuration that runs your bash script and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my MAC and it picked up the new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For me at least, the only thing that works was to put this in the `Shell path` variable inside of Tools > Terminal :

`/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Sorry for the abuse of system here. Congrats on being my "Strunk and White" twin -- we both received this badge around the same time and have similar overall points.  And this despite your English! I also like the "unsung hero" badge - don't have one myself, but a nice concept.

Answer (score 0):

Open settings, Tools->Terminal->Shell path, just set `/bin/bash`。Reopen IDE, open terminal to test it. If it doesn't work, run `exit` and then reopen a new terminal, maybe it will take effects.