# What is the command to use to run the default shell in login mode?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, zsh

I'm testing [alacritty](https://github.com/jwilm/alacritty) and it has a config where you provide the absolute path to the program and the args for the shell to run. Which would ordinarily either be `/bin/bash -l` or `/bin/zsh -l`.

The thing is that i'd like to keep my configuration the same, but some of my machines I run bash and some I run zsh. So, I'd like to use the standard program which delegates the selection of the user's shell.

Normally this seems to be `/usr/bin/login`, but when I specify this program, it actually prompts me for user and password, which is far from ideal.

As far as I can tell, iTerm2 does somehow use `login` but in a way that doesn't prompt for credentials. I wonder how I could set this up.

Actually upon some [quick searching](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/master/sources/shell_launcher.c), we find that iterm actually implements its own shell launcher because of limitations seen with Apple's `login`. Interesting.

Comment: The value of `$SHELL` should be the user's login shell: `"$SHELL" -l`.

Comment: the terminal emulator would be launched as a standalone app outside of the context of a command line shell. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can get an absolute path to the current user's login shell by parsing `/etc/passwd`:

`getent passwd $LOGNAME | cut -d ':' -f 7`

You could potentially place a subshell in the config which will evaluate to the real path:

`$(getent passwd $LOGNAME | cut -d ':' -f 7)`

Comment: I don't think the config works like this or supports execution of shell commands. It is nice to learn about getent. Although it does not exist on macOS.

Comment: BusyBox doesn't have getent so you may try `grep ^$(id -un): /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 7-`  from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16375660/1049542