# Get the current macOS shell using Qt

Tags: macos, qt, qprocess, dscl

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16375519/how-to-get-the-default-shell) I can get it using this command:

```
dscl . -read ~/ UserShell
```

So, I wrote this code using `Qt`:

```
QProcess p;
p.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
p.start("dscl", QStringList() << "." << "-read" << "~/" << "UserShell");
p.waitForFinished();
auto result = QString::fromUtf8(p.readAll());
```

But, the `result` is empty. What am I doing wrong? This command works fine in the Terminal app.

**Addition #1**. This works, but it looks stupid :)

```
p.start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" << "dscl . -read ~/ UserShell")
```

Comment: Using that overload of `QProcess::start` will bypass the shell meaning the `~/` token is not expanded.  You need to perform that expansion yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only alternative is to expand the `~` yourself.  So something like...

```
p.start("dscl", QStringList() << "." << "-read" << QDir::homePath() << "UserShell");
```